# How to restore Java Minecraft server after power outage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I just experienced a power outage and I lost my multiplayer Minecraft Java server world (which I've spent a ton of time crafting). When I restarted the server after the outage, a new world map was generated.

Unfortunately, I don't have any backups (that I'm aware of)  I'm in my "world" directory and have some files in the "region"and "player data" directory that were saved before the outage. Can these be used to restore the world?

Comment: That is very weird, chunks shouldn't reset just because the power went off. Can you upload the entire world folder, please?

Comment: I agree, I didn't expect that either!!  Here is the world folder [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1wWcssgSiTyWoePM37MOcAyCBHQU9m5)

Comment: I see some built structures at x466 z-86, so the middle region files aren't completely reset.

Comment: Your villager farm is really inefficient, because most doors don't count. You need more blocks blocking sky light for the ground in front of the doors than on the other side (or the other way around).

Comment: (I mean the one with Netherrack.) In general I see a lot of things still working, but near 0 0 everything is regular terrain. I can't realy see where the reset chunks end, since I see no structure that is broken directly on a chunk border. Are you sure you aren't just in a different location than expected?

Comment: Wow, great, thank you.  I didn't realize the spawn point had changed, it is my world!!  And thanks for the advice on the villager farm, I'm just starting to get into these systems

Comment: So nothing was changed except the spawn point? In that case you can post that as a self-answer and accept that instead of the answer that didn't actually help you. To figure out why the spawn point was changed, we would need a backup from before the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the server on your local network, on your own system or on a public server?

If you ran the server yourself the server files should be in the directory you ran your server from.

---

If you ran the server from your client it should be in your minecraft client folder (see below)

```
Windows computers 

Press Win+R, then type %appdata%\.minecraft, then press Ok.


OS X

In the Finder, from the Go menu, select 'Go to Folder', then type: ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft, and click Go.
```

[Detailed description](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1480874-where-are-minecraft-files-stored-)

---

If you ran your server on a public server there should be some periodic server back-ups you could access in a way. There is a boat-load of different scenario's for this depending on how this server was set-up and who managed the server. More information would be needed to answer this scenario further.

---

If you managed to locate your server files I would probably copy the files to another folder on your system and run the server once. This shall generate the server files it needs again with a blank world. After this is done, shut down the server and place your copied files back (overwrite Yes). This should be the last state your server was saved in. This is ofcourse excluding that your server files were damaged beyond repair due to your power outage. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm running the server on my own system.  I looked in the appdata directory, but I only seem to find the single player worlds in there.  Do you know what directory the server world would be stored in?

Comment: Its been quite some time since I touched the server files myself. Back when I played around with server files we had a seperate .jar file we had to run and this would generate the files needed. Among those were the world files. As of some time I believe it's possible to host a local server from in-game through the settings? (you probably know more about this than me) If that is the case I wouldn't be surprised if your 'multiplayer' world is just a single player world in disguise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried to perform the backup but it didn't restore my world.  Based on the "Modified Date" of the region files, it appears that 4 of the region files were modified after the power outage (    r.0.0  |  r.0.-1,  |   r.-1.0   |  r.-1.-1    ).  I tried removing those files but it caused an entirely new world to be generated.  Are there backups of those *.mca region files?

Comment: Thanks, upon further review and help from  Fabian Röling, I realize that the spawn point had changed and my world is still intact.